# How to use emoji type things in IEEE author names

Tags: footnotes, titles, ieeetran

How to do something like this in the IEEE trans paper format.

[image]

Comment: These are just footnotes, using custom characters (color emojis, in this case). To be honest, I don't know what I think about using, e.g., a pizza slice emoji to denote affiliation with an Italian university.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't want to know which stereotypical emojis would be used if the authors would be affiliated to an African or Arabian university... Better just use asterisks or something similar neutral. But only my personal opinion, of course ;)